# Create an SVG image of shapes with a shared border using Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, autodesk-fusion-360

Is it technically possible to make an SVG image of shapes with a shared border, or is there some technical limitation? I have this image of tessellations [image] where a border is shared, and I'm wondering if it is actually possible to represent it with SVG? I have created this image with Inkscape bezier curve tool and "joined" the nodes such that the border should be shared, but when I export it as SVG go to load it in Fusion 360, I see two separate closed contours for each lizard, as shown in this picture [image: fusion 360].

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There is no way to have two closed shapes share a single border with each other.  A closed path cannot join to another path.  It's not possible.  You can have two closed paths butt up to each other, so that the borders overlap. What is this actually going to be used for?  Why do you need them to share a border? Why would it matter?

Comment: If you are looking for a tutorial to make an Escher-style tessellation, there's [a video tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDshMQ5HbGk&t=62s) which might be useful.  If you do it this way, there will be no gaps.